# How to filter data based on a time parameter in Access?

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I have a query from another thread which goes through a list of different events and pulls out the most recent event and puts it into a list. The code I'm using is:

```
SELECT Cleaning1, Max(Date1) AS most_recent
FROM CleaningLog
GROUP BY Cleaning1;
```

Cleaning1 is the column that has the different cleanings, and Date1 is the column that has the date the cleaning occurred, and CleaningLog is the name of the table. I currently have a macro in Access which is an OpenQuery, query. I am having it open the above query, and then having it view as a data sheet and it's in edit mode.

What I am stuck on, is getting a subsequent macro/query/vba code to take the datasheet the query produces and going through each item and determining if they're over due to be cleaned. I tried having a Make Table query, but the problem is, there is no user friendly way to refresh that table without having to delete it (I am having unskilled workers use this Access sheet).

I am wondering if there's a way to look at the most recent cleaning's date, what the query produces, and filter the dates out that are over due for a cleaning, specified by a parameter. I have been looking at this webpage to start playing with the notation, but I haven't been able to come up with much that is useful.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-query-criteria-3197228C-8684-4552-AC03-ABA746FB29D8

Another problem that I am encountering is that each cleaning doesn't have the same time frame in which is needs to be cleaned.

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Comment: Users should not work directly with tables and queries, they should interface with forms and reports. Open form filtered to desired records.  Do you have a table that has field for the frequency for each item's cleaning? Would be easiest if used a common unit of measure for all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to modify the query above to show entries with a max date lower than they should be. Below shows entries that haven't been cleaned in 30 days, for instance.

```
SELECT Cleaning1, Max(Date1) AS most_recent
FROM CleaningLog
GROUP BY Cleaning1
HAVING Max(Date1) < Now() - 30;
```